# Style image is not created

Tags: 7, media

### I have a D7 (7.72) news website (multi-lingual), it started on 2023-06-07, that no image upload or update could create style in sites/default/files/styles although it uploads to the sites/default/files folder. It is the same on all content types. The path and also itok is being generated but the styled file is not there!
Web server is LiteSpeed (php 7.73 , db: MariaDB 10), I have 19968 nodes, 21397 images with a total size of 4.18G in sites/default/files folder.
I have also checked permission 777, also updated all core (to 7.97) with all modules, but none helped. I wrote a small php code to copy a file to the folder, manually copied files with no problem, and I get no php error in the php-log file. I cleared all image caches but lost all the images and none could be re-generated, so I had to go back to back up and a day ago. I have 3 other domains running D7 on the same hosting plan, all of them are ok.
Can you please help me or give me a clue?
Thank you,

ps. Now I have installed HTTPRL and I get this:
Core    drupal_http_request()
Your system or network configuration does not allow Drupal to access web pages. This could be due to your webserver configuration or PHP settings. Debug info: Array (
[0] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[count] => 1
[time] => 7289.85
[mode] => 2
[blocking] => FALSE
[url] => https://191.101.104.233/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1
[request] => Array (
[https://191.101.104.233/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1] => stdClass Object (
[url] => https://191.101.104.233/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1
[status] => Connecting.
[code] => -1004
[chunk_size] => 1024
[data] =>
[request] => POST /httprl_async_function_callback?count=1 HTTP/1.0
Host: [www.iranstar.com](http://www.iranstar.com)
Connection: closed
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 554

Comment: Are there no errors whatsoever in Drupal's, PHP's or the web server's error logs?

I found this: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2021-11-23/drupal-8-cant-generate-image-style-on-openlitespeed

Comment: Surprisingly, no error is logged (error_log has no new entry, .log is not even been created since I removed it long time ago). I tried both of rewrite and ImageInfo, and even with ImageInfo and using load with httprl there is no log, no file in style yet the file only is at the root of the files.
The only error I get is in Drupal's admin/reports/dblog as access denied once media file upload is completed but fails to show the thumbnail in the add new content, and it is a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the strange behavior of the built-in CDN on the server. I turned that off and everything went back to normal. Also please consider adding "Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" to /sites/default/files/.htaccess and apply to its subdirectories

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).